# Sort Stocks by MarketCap

Tags: curated-data, sorting, finance

If I correctly understand, here I have all the existing companies listed in every market and identified by each real name:

```
assets = FinancialData["Stocks"];
names = FinancialData[assets, "Name"];
```

How could I order the element of `names` vector within an other vector where elements are ordered by `"MarketCap"` property of `FinancialData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names = FinancialData[{"GE", "GOOGL", "MSFT", "AAPL", "HPQ"}, "Name"];
mcaps = FinancialData[{"GE", "GOOGL", "MSFT", "AAPL", "HPQ"}, "MarketCap"];

sortednames = names[[Ordering[mcaps]]]
```

> ```
> {"HP Inc", "General Electric Co", "Alphabet Inc", "Apple Inc", "Microsoft Corp"}
> ```

Alternatively, you can construct a list of name and market cap pairs and sort by the second column:

```
sortednamesmcaps = SortBy[Last] @
 FinancialData[{"GE", "GOOGL", "MSFT", "AAPL", "HPQ"}, {"Name",  "MarketCap"}] 

Grid @ sortednamesmcaps
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kglr, the second solution was exactly what I was looking for! Any ideas why it doesn't work with this?

`sortednamesmcaps = SortBy[Last] @
 FinancialData["Stocks", {"Name",  "MarketCap"}][[;;100]]; 

Grid @ sortednamesmcaps`

Doesn't any company has `MarketCap` property? My final goal would be from all stocks select those whose `MarketCap` value is Greater than a fixed value..